# What type of bifurcation point is this?

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation, fixed-points

Consider the function $$x'=rx-\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
I'm asked to find the bifurcation points and classify if they are saddle node, trans-critical, pitchfork, etc.

One method we have been using in class is to look at the Taylor series and cut off an appropriate number of terms to get it in the normal form for one of the various types of bifurcations.  So I did this on this problem and got,

$$rx - (x-x^3+O(x^5))$$
$$rx-x+x^3$$
$$x(r-1)+x^3$$
Now if we let $\sigma=r-1$ we get $x\sigma +x^3$ which is exactly the normal form for a subcritical pitchfork bifurcation.  My problem is when I graph the function as $r$ varies it looks more like a saddle node bifurcation because fixed points are being created and destroyed.  For this problem when $r \geq 1$ it looks like we have exactly one fixed point, then when $0<r<1$ there are 3 fixed points and then when $r \leq 0$ we have one fixed point again. I'm unsure how to classify this equation if anyone could correct me if my thinking or work is wrong. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: $0$ is always a fixed point and $r$ has critical values $0$ and $1$. If $r$ increases, then, as it passes $0$, two nonzero fixed points are created, and they’re both unstable. As $r$ passes $1$, they’re both killed and $0$ becomes unstable. This is a subcritical pitchfork bifurcation. Now draw the bifurcation diagram. Excellent work!

Comment: Okay that's what I was thinking. So it's alright that the two nonzero fixed points get killed, it's still classified as a subcritical pitchfork bifurcation?

Comment: That is correct and I would draw the bifurcation diagram to prove it to yourself.

Comment: The bifurcation diagram isn't going to look like a regular pitchfork bifurcation is it? its' going to look like a line a $x=0$ for all $r$ but then its gonna have 2 curves going off to plus and minus infinity as r approaches zero from the positive starting at 1, correct?

Comment: Plot $r$ (horizontal axis) versus $x_*$ (vertical access) for $$r = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$$ and use symmetry. It looks like a dashed Gaussian curve, but shown vertically and then is a dashed line on the $r$ axis that starts at the top of that dashed Gaussian looking curve. Clear?

Comment: Okay yeah that makes sense. Thanks so much.

Comment: See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F(x%5E2+%2B+1)+%3D+s Of course, add the dashed lines and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$  is always a fixed point and $r$ has critical values $0$ and $1$. If $r$ increases, then, as it passes $0$, two nonzero fixed points are created, and they’re both unstable. As $r$ passes $1$, they’re both destroyed and $0$ becomes unstable.

You should get a bifurcation diagram that looks something like

[image]

This appears to be a subcritical pitchfork bifurcation.

Doing the Taylor expansion of $f(x, r) = rx-\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ near $x = 0$,

$$f(x, r) \approx \underbrace{ (r - 1) x + x^3}_{\text{Normal}} + O(x^5)$$

This is the [*Normal form of the subcritical pitchfork bifurcation*](https://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2011/Spring/physics221a/LECTURES/CH02_BIFURCATIONS.pdf) (see Section $2.1.3$) at $x_* = 0, r_* = 1$.

Comment: Here is a similar posting, but not exact https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617730/normal-form-of-subcritical-pitchfork-bifurcation